# Python3.3 header preferred over Python2.7 header by gcc

Tags: python, python-2.7, gcc, python-3.x, include-path

I am trying to compile a code which uses the Python.h header. In fact it is the lcm library.

Now, I have Python2.7 and Python3.3 installed on my system. The respective header filer are found in `/usr/include/python2.7/` and `/usr/include/python3.3m/`.

The problem is that the code needs the 2.7 version, but gcc always prefers the 3.3 version.

I tried setting `./configure --prefix /bla/bla CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/python2.7/` and `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python2.7`, none of which worked.

An intermediate workaround is to change the code to `#include <python2.7/Python.h>` but that makes it unportable, so it will not serve as a fix for the lcm people...

There must be a way!!!

Comment: Did you try `--with-python=...` yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: thanks for the comment, tried it right now, and no... doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC probably prefers the 3.3 version if it's installed as the default that's run when you call 'python' without a version? You could always point that binary at the 2.7 to make it the default on your system..

Looking at the m4 source, seems like you might be able to do the following on one line:

PYTHON=/path/to/python2.7 PYTHON_INCLUDES="-I/usr/include/python2.7" ./configure --prefix /bla/bla

Comment: The "build it with whatever" is the step that is failing because there is c code, that does not compile with the wrong version of the Python.h header file.

Comment: Updated my answer to hopefully a more enlightening answer

Comment: Strange enough, the ``PYTHON=/path/to/python2.7`` did the trick. I can omit the ``PYTHON_INCLUDES=...``. Strange, because my default python points to python2.7 already and configure finds it. But it only works with the PYTHON variable.

Comment: Probably m4 weirdness, I found the variables in m4/python.m4 fwiw